# ob_get_content() output incorrect

Tags: php, ob-start, php-5.5, ob-get-contents

I'm experiencing some problems with ob_start function, probably due to the new PHP 5.5

What I'm trying to do is render some PHP from a third file using inside ob_start.

Here the code:

```
function fetch()
{
    extract($this->a_vars); // Extract the vars to local namespace

    ob_start();                                              

    include (templateClass.php);  // This file is just 'text'
    $s_contents = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $s_contents;
}
```

Basically what I'm doing is extracting some variables in the local namespace that templateClass will use to render/show some pieces of the text, for example:

```
...

function func1() {
    return true;
}

<?if(isset($var1)):?>
    function func2() {
        return 2;
    }
<?endif;?>

...
```

But my variable $s_contents has exactly ALL the content of the file including the php code inside which is not being interpreted. What I need is to get all the php blocks interpreted and the output will be my final usable PHP class.

Any idea?

Comment: `<?` are you sure that `short_open_tag` is enabled in `php.ini`? Missing quotes? `include (templateClass.php);`

Comment: short_open_tag is active... and the file looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

1. `include (templateClass.php);`
   I hope you have putted quotes in it. Like `include ("templateClass.php");`